# Modifying JScrollPane's Column Header

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane that contains a JPanel. This JPanel has 2 tables: for some reasons, i prefeer to have just one JScrollPanes for both the tables.

The problem is that i should ALWAYS show the two table's headers, and to do this i have to set a proper custom column header for the JScrollPanel. How can this be done? I've tried setColumnHeader but can't find a way to let this thing done. The final JScrollPanel's custom colum header must contain both the table headers, one one the left and the other on the right side (visually making a unique header)

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: @ MyPasswordIsLasercats:idk what it is

Comment: SSCCE stands for _Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example_. You might want to click on the link I provided in the first comment. SSCCEs are very welcome on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [setColumnHeaderView()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setColumnHeaderView%28java.awt.Component%29) is what you are looking for?